STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ascending and descending, VHDL code for mux
please stop downvoting i have to know the answer
The aim is to make an 8-1 mux using (2) 4-1 mux and only one 2-1 mux using VHDL:
ENTITY mux4-1 IS
    PORT(W:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWN TO 0);
         S:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWN TO 0);
         f:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END mux4-1

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF mux4-1
BEGIN
WITH S SELECT
f <= W(0) WHEN "00",
     W(1) WHEN "01",
     W(2) WHEN "10",
     W(3) WHEN "11";
END behavior;

For the first stage I want to use 2 of these to make the 8-1 mux and my question is: when I'm defining the port (defining the w input) can I define it as (0 to 7) or not because the order of mux4-1 is descending and I will have to use it later so it should be:
-- (7 DOWN TO 0)
ENTITY mux8-1 IS
PORT(W: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 TO 7)...)
-- ...
stage0: mux4-1 PORT MAP(W(0 TO 3),...)
  

and im asking this because as i know the ascending order of the vector is for "Big endian" while the descending order is for "Little endian" so the first 4-1mux would only works for "little endian" while the 8-1 mux would only work for "Big endian"

Please do not feel bad about the down votes (I did not), they just tell other visitors that your question is unclear, making it less worth to read for their own issue. It is nothing against you as a person. The reason for closure is also stated, so you might want to [edit] your question to extend it to a minimal, complete and reproducible example, including a test bench. Also, please add details about your concerns of endianness, and why it is important for your design.

The order (up or down) is not relevant here as long as you keep the consistency between the selected input and the select code, like you did in the example code for the mux4-1 (0 to 3):
W(0) WHEN "00",

You also need to keep the consistency when connecting each instance of the mux4-1 to the main mux8-1 architecture.

sorry i didnt fully understand this, my question is: if i use little endian in mux4-1 then  should i also use it in mux8-1 ?like for example if im implementing a function in the first mux4-1 that will build mux8-1 where w0=1,w1=0,w2=1,w3=1 and the selector bits are "10" according to mux4-1 w0 is w3 and w1 is w2 thus it will choose 0 but if i wrote the code and the logic_vector was ascending  it will choose w2=1 , thats my point

@winstar345 Remember that VHDL is a hardware description language, and draw a schematic of the complete mux8. I'm sure things become clear then.
